# How to post data to javascript using org.w3c.dom.Document

Tags: java, javascript, android, jsoup, domdocument

I was using JSoup in order to post data and call javascript functions, but now I want to change it because it slows up my application.

This is my current implementation:

`doc = Jsoup.connect(SRC).data("__EVENTTARGET", name).data("__EVENTARGUMENT", "").data(name, value)
            .data("__VIEWSTATE", doc.select("input#__VIEWSTATE").attr("value")).data("__LASTFOCUS", "").post();`

Now I want to use `org.w3c.dom.Document` in order to do the same thing.
How can I do that here?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution on my own:

```
List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("__EVENTTARGET", eventTarget));
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("__EVENTARGUMENT", "1"));
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("__VIEWSTATE", doc.select("input#__VIEWSTATE").attr("value")));
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("__LASTFOCUS", ""));
post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
// Execute HTTP Post Request
response = client.execute(post);
```